# Supervisor doesn't start: couldn't chdir to ... EACCES

Tags: amazon-ec2, django, supervisord, gunicorn

I'm setting up an ec2 server to run a django project with ngnix & gunicorn. The server is running Amazon Linux.  When I run the start gunicorn command from the command line, it starts up the server, but when I try to run it from supervisor I get the following error:

```
supervisor: couldn't chdir to /home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/wakeup-site/django-site: EACCES
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

This happens when I run supervisor as sudo or as my own user. 
Permission for the dir: /home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/wakeup-site/django-site

```
drwxrwxrwx 15 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Mar  6 08:21 django-site
```

Relevant Supervisor.conf lines:

```
[program:wakeup]
command=./start_gunicorn.bash
directory="/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/wakeup-site/django-site"
user=ec2-user
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/wakeup-site/django-site/logs/supervisorconf.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/wakeup-site/django-site/logs/gunicorn_stderr.log
```

start_gunicorn.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Starts the Gunicorn server
set -e

# Activate the virtualenv for this project
%(ACTIVATE)s

# Start gunicorn going
exec gunicorn wakeup.wsgi:application -c gunicorn.conf.py
```

I have tried removing the directory line from supervisor, and just making the command a full path, tried running as sudo and removing the ect2-user line with chown the whole dir as root.
When I run

```
exec gunicorn wakeup.wsgi:application -c gunicorn.conf.py
```

from the command line it works and I can browse to the site.

Can someone please help??

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, I am facing a similar error while using Celery.

Comment: @Shiva I'm so sorry, not working on the project anymore & can't remember what happened.

Answer (score 0):

This look like a permission issue.
The first question to ask yourself if "the owner of the directory is ec2-user" else change it appropriately to the actual user

> > user=ec2-user

Comment: The question shows that the owner is ec2-user

Comment: @RalfFriedl why the down vote? i was merely pointing the line out to the Op to give permission to the ec2-user in the proper directory....  i hope you understand that

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just pointed out that the ownership is already correct.